# UIPickerView row selection

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView with two components.
It works fine when the user scrolls each component until it reaches the desired value.
But I want it to behave like the picker in the calendar or the clock apps. Meaning: When the user presses a certain value in one of the components, I want that component to automatically turn that row to be the selected row (so the user doesn't always have to scroll, he/she can also simply select the value they want).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you,

~Chonch

Comment: Do you want a UIDatePicker (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)?

Comment: No. I want a customized picker with two components...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is standard picker behaviour and it should work so automatically.

If your picker does not select tapped row automatically try to set `userInteractionEnabled` property to **NO** for the view you return from `viewForRow:` method in picker data source.

Comment: I use UIView with a UILabel inside it as the return value for viewForRow. I tried to add userInteractionEnabled for both the UILabel and the UIView but it doesn't seem to help.
Can you think of any other option?

Comment: Could you post your viewForRow: method?

Comment: if (component == 0)
 {
  Style *curStyle = [self.styleArray objectAtIndex:row];
  
  // Create the view for the current part
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 46);
  UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  
  // Add the part name
  frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 110, 46);
  UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  lbl.text = curStyle.styleName;
  lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  [view addSubview:lbl];
  [lbl release];

  view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  
  return view;
 }
 else
  return [self.partsArray objectAtIndex:row];

Comment: So sorry, I had similar problem some time before and posted solution from memory, but remembered general approach and completely confused the details. See updated answer.